# Change default value to a null for date column in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, null, default

How to change the default value of a date column to a null ? Not able to add a new column to a mysql table because of the default property of the date column.

Table name is task_value;
Date column is pdate;

I tried ALTER TABLE task_value  MODIFY( pdate DATE NULL );

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: *I tried* Beauty is evil... Study [ALTER TABLE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) - there is no parenthesis in it. And if you need to set default value only then use `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SET DEFAULT`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
ALTER TABLE task_value ALTER COLUMN pdate DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```